# Find the midsegment of a rectangular trapezoid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

> In a trapezoid $ABCD(AB||CD)$, $\angle ADC = 120^\circ$ and
>   $AB=AD=2CD$. $M$ is the midpoint of $AD$. Find the length of the
>   midsegment $MN$ if $   h_{MB}$ in $\triangle MBC$ is $3$ cm.

$\angle ADC + \angle BAD = 180 ^\circ$, thus $\angle BAD = 60 ^\circ$. Let $DD_1$ is the height of $ABCD$ through $D$. $\triangle AD_1M$ is equilateral, so $AM=AD_1=D_1M$. Now I am trying to show $BD_1=AD_1$ but don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

It could be reasoned that $\triangle BMC$ is an equilateral triangle. So that $MN = h = 3cm$

Use the fact that $\triangle CDM$ and $\triangle BD'M$ are both isosceles triangles and, then, $\angle ABM = \angle MCD = 30$.

Comment: This will come after I show $AD_1 = BD_1$, but I do not know how to do it. I wrote it in the post.

Comment: The 60-degree right ADD' gives you $AD_1=AD/2=DC$

Comment: Got it. I'd forgotten $AB=AD$.

Comment: I've just looked at the answers and it is saying $8$ $cm$.

Comment: it can be easily seen that triangle BCM is equilateral and its heights  MN and $CC_1 $ are equal. that is MN=3 Cm.